# Remove comma in output in crystal report

Tags: string, crystal-reports

in my crystal report, I have created a subreport in my main report. This subreport,  I want to have an output like this {ID_PRJ}-{UF6}-{UF3}-{DESCR_PRJ} which is a combination from many db tables. However, the {ID_PRJ} should be in text value but turns out it read it as number value as it has the commas.

For example:
Target output : 5031-A-B-KEJORA
Output : 5,031-A-B-KEJORA
How to remove the thousand separator as when I right click on the text object, I cannot found the Format Field. It only has Text, Format Text, Format Painter, Edit Text.

And how to insert the formula to convert number into string?

Answer (score 0):

The `ToText()` function is how you convert values into strings.  You may see some examples from others that use the `CStr()` function as well.  `ToText()` and `CStr()` are equivalent functions.

When converting Number and Currency values with these functions, you will want to use `ToText(x, y, z, w)` specifically.  Where x is the Number of Currency value you want to convert to a string.  Then y is number of decimal places to maintain, z is a single character string that indicates what character to use as the thousands separator, and w is a single character string that indicates what character to use as the decimal separator.

To apply this, you formula would now look like this:

```
ToText({ID_PRJ}, 0, "", "")-{UF6}-{UF3}-{DESCR_PRJ}
```

This will ensure that `{ID_PRJ}` is converted to a string with zero characters after the decimal, and an empty string for the thousands separator, and an empty string as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is partially correct, but you can't combine (concatenate) content that way. Try a formula like this:

```
ToText({ID_PRJ}, 0, "") + "-" + {UF6} + "-" + {UF3} + "-" + {DESCR_PRJ}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching my error!  I should have noticed the missing syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Given you are able to concatenate the fields together means your {ID_PRJ} field is not actually a number which needs converting but actually is already text, which is formatted with the comma thousand separators within. To remove the commas you could use replace, like so

```
Replace({ID_PRJ}, ",", "") + "-" + {UF6} + "-" + {UF3} + "-" + {DESCR_PRJ}
```